# How to display output when field exists in other table?

Tags: sql

Goodmorning,

I am still pretty new to SQL (got two courses planned in the near future) so this might be a very easy solution. I just cannot figure it out. I want to generate an Excel file (spool?) that shows output when it had one of the PR.BEW_STATUS AND exists in the table INVENTARIS. I can't get the EXIST command to work and I am not totally sure if the output I am getting now it what I want.

Who can help me? :)

```
   SELECT 

PR.PRE_INV_ID,
PI.INVENTARISNR

FROM

PRESTAMKAART PR,
PRESTAMKAART_INV PI,
INVENTARIS I

WHERE
  
PR.PRE_INV_ID = PI.PRE_INV_ID
    AND PR.BEW_STATUS IN ('0','1','2','5')
    AND PI.INVENTARISNR = I.INVENTARISNR

Order BY PR.PRE_INV_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:-

SELECT PR.PRE_INV_ID,PI.INVENTARISNR FROM PRESTAMKAART PR,PRESTAMKAART_INV PI WHERE PR.PRE_INV_ID = PI.PRE_INV_ID  AND PR.BEW_STATUS IN ('0','1','2','5')
AND Exists(select 1 from INVENTARIS I where PI.INVENTARISNR= I.INVENTARISNR)
Order BY PR.PRE_INV_ID;

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This seems to do the trick and I am going to test it. I forgot to put the EXISTS line between ( ). What does the "1" do exactly?